# T SQL - Passing table variables through a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a stored procedure:

```
exec my_sp ?,?
```

I can execute this stored procedure by adding two values e.g.

```
exec my_sp 'value 1','value 2'
```

Now this is where things get tricky.....

I have a table for example

```
1  |  2
aa   bb
cc   dd
```

and so on.......

Now I want to pass my table values through and create one table of results e.g.

```
exec my_sp 'aa','bb'

exec my_sp 'cc','dd'
```

and so on..........

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it sadly seems like the answer is using a cursor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variable as parameter on a Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903923/pass-variable-as-parameter-on-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: What is my_sp doing?  Is it just returning results, or is it inserting records into a table?

Comment: You should search on how to Pass table to a stored proc,see moto gp answer for some hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (unfortunately) is via a `CURSOR`.  I renamed the columns you had in the question from `1` and `2` to `A` and `B` for sanity's sake.

```
Declare @c_a varchar (10),
        @c_b varchar (10)

Declare cur Cursor For
(
    Select  A, B
    From    YourTable
)

Open cur
While (1 = 1)
Begin
    Fetch Next From cur Into @c_a, @c_b

    If (@@Fetch_Status <> 0) Break

    Execute my_sp @c_a, @c_b
End
Close cur
Deallocate cur
```

Comment: This may not be the most efficient way of performing this query however my query is a one off so I have used your cursor query but declared a #temp_table at the start and then in the while clause inserted into the temp table. Cheers for your help with this Siyual and apologies for the poorly named example column names!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you alter your procedure to accept `table type` as *input parameter* instead of `variables`.

Then you can pass all the values in your table to the procedure in a single shot  and get things done for all the rows in the procedure.

Create table type

```
Create type my_sp_param as table (col1 varchar(2),col2 varchar(2))
```

Alter procedure

```
Alter procedure my_sp (@param my_sp_param)
as
..
```

To call the procedure with table type input

```
declare @param my_sp_param 

insert into @param (col1,col2)
select [1],[2] from yourtable

exec my_sp  @param
```

If you cannot alter the procedure then you have to use a CURSOR or WHILE loop to pass each row as input to your procedure, which is highly not recommended.